# How to access iframe from its inner document

Tags: html, iframe, google-chrome-extension, autofill

I'm creating a chrome extension and was wondering how to get the iframe element and its attributes from its content document. The situation I'm running into is one where I have multiple iframes with identical content documents but I have to fill each one of them differently base on an attribute of each iframe. But the script injects only into the content document of iframe so I need to access each documents' surrounding iframe.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need a content script running in the main page that owns the iframes. That script will listen to `message` event on `window` which will be triggered by your iframe script calling parent.postMessage. Then the main script will loop through all iframe elements and compare event's `source` to the iframe's `contentWindow`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your answer! Sound good but when I try to access the ```event.source``` i get: ```Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.adidas.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame```. Any thoughts?

Comment: Look for examples of using postMessage. The only allowed type of access is reading the `source` property itself, you can't peek inside of it.